# How to find which raster cells are overlapped by polygons

Tags: polygon, clip, overlapping-features, rasterization, command-line

(QGIS 3.22)
I'm trying to compare a raster layer with a vector layer and find all the raster cells overlapped by a vector. Unfortunately, the polygons are much smaller than the pixels of the raster, 2000 features into 82x83 pixels. I tried rasterizing the vector layer with `-at` to use raster calculator, but the cells don't line up correctly, even when specifying the raster layer as the extent and entering the exact resolution. The raster layer I'm trying to line the polygons up with has been clipped via a different vector layer, if that matters at all.

Any better way to go about this or perhaps some small command I am missing? I just want to know all the raster cells that have a polygon anywhere inside of them.

Comment: Why not ask why you don't get the pixels lining up when rasterizing with -at and show us your exact parameters? Because I can confidently state that the pixels will line up 
exactly if you use the correct parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new at QGIS, but I went back and realized that different CRS files affects the rasterization compared to the cells of the background raster, so I went through and reprojected everything. That still didn't work at first, but then I tried clipping to the extent of the clipped background raster rather than the mask that I had used to clip it. Probably the most satisfying moment in my life, I honestly have spent 20+ hours in the last 3 days trying to do that single task.